# Sending a custom parameter from a form into a custom Paperclip Processor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have a custom Paperclip processor which extracts a screenshot from an MP4 using FFMPEG. This is working very well but I would like for the user to be able to select the time at which the screenshot is taken in the video in the upload form before it is processed, which has so far eluded me.

**upload.rb**

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base

has_attached_file :uploaded_file, 
    styles: { 
        screenshot: { :processors => [:screenshot], :format => 'png' }
    }, 
    default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"

default_scope order('created_at DESC')

def paperclip_screenshot_time
    # I'm attempting to pull in params[:screenshot_time] (set in the view)
    self.screenshot_time.to_s
end
```

end

The above does not work, however if I change the `paperclip_screenshot_time` method to:

```
def paperclip_screenshot_time
     '5' 
end
```

It works fine.

Here is an excerpt from the processor, which as I say is also working fine:

**screenshot.rb**

```
module Paperclip
class Screenshot < Processor

    def initialize(file, options = {}, attachment = nil)
        super
        @file           = file
        @options        = options
        @instance       = attachment.instance
        @current_format = '.*'
        @basename       = File.basename(@file.path, @current_format)
        @whiny          = options[:whiny].nil? ? true : options[:whiny]
    end

    def target
        @attachment.instance
    end

    def make

        # Removed for brevity

        begin
            system('ffmpeg -i ' + @file.path + ' -ss 00:00:0' + target.paperclip_screenshot_time.to_s + ' -f image2 -vframes 1 ' + tmp_dir + '/' + tmp_filename)
        end

       # Removed for brevity

    end
end
end
```

...and the relevant field from the view.

**upload.jst.erb**

```
<input name="upload[screenshot_time]" type="number" min="0" max="9" value="4" class="js-form-input" />
```

The field is also permitted in the controller:

**uploads_controller.rb**

```
def upload_params
  params[:upload].permit(:uploaded_file, :title, :screenshot_time)
end
```

So, to re-iterate the problem seems to be in setting `paperclip_screenshot_time` with the value from `upload[screenshot_time]` in the view. How should I go about doing this?

Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was the order in which the upload params were set in the controller.

So, in order for `title` and `screenshot_time` to be accessible in the processor they had to come *before* `uploaded_file`. So by changing the upload_params method to this:

```
def upload_params
   params[:upload].permit(:title, :screenshot_time, :uploaded_file)
end
```

It all works smoothly.